# Eclipse CDT C/C++ Indexer not detecting few classes

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv

I am currently working with OpenCV Android NDK, When I opened a sample project the CPP editor always show an error "IDetector not defined"

```
class CascadeDetectorAdapter: public DetectionBasedTracker::IDetector
{
public:
    CascadeDetectorAdapter(cv::Ptr<cv::CascadeClassifier> detector):
```

But compilation and execution working properly, I am able the run the project

But the errors in the editor is kind of weird, I could not ctrl+click the class, But **CascadeClassifier** is also a CPP class inside **opencv2/objdetect.hpp** which is properly indexed and I am able to the auto completions but **opencv2/objdetect/detection_based_tracker.hpp** is not indexed properly

I have another HPP file say abcd.hpp and placed similar class with a different name

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_OBJDETECT_ABCD_HPP__
#define __OPENCV_OBJDETECT_ABCD_HPP__

namespace cv
{

class CV_EXPORTS DetectionBasedTracker1
{
    public:
    class IDetector1
    {

    };
};

};
#endif
```

Here the **DetectionBasedTracker1** is detected but **DetectionBasedTracker1::IDetector1** is not detected

Is this a problem related to nested class?

Can anyone help me solving this please.

--EDIT--

it seems on the top inside **detection_based_tracker.hpp** there is the following code

```
#if defined(__linux__) || defined(LINUX) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__ANDROID__) || \
  (defined(__cplusplus) &&  __cplusplus > 201103L) || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1700)
```

If I remove this code and so re-index then the error disappeared

Is it possible to bypass this **#if define** with eclipse environment variables or C/C++ Macros or assemblies?

Comment: The Eclipse indexer is only run after a build. Do you still have problems after you build the project?

Comment: Yes, I still have the problem after build, but build, compile, run everything work fine, except the editor shows the red colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add # Symbols in your project

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> # Symbols

Add **__ANDROID__** here and give some value like **1**

Then the indexer should be able to bypass the maro and identify the class definitions

Comment: Yes, As soon as I introduce the grey disabled section inside the **detection_based_tracker.hpp** disappeared and the indexer is able to detect the classes and I am able to ctrl+click now, Thanks a lot